# Why isn't it possible to call a function on an tuple object?

Tags: python, function, pyqt, tuples

The bStart and bStop click functions literally do the same, yet the bStop function calls an error.

Why isn't it possible to call .hide() on a tuple object?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QFrame, QGridLayout, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QSpacerItem, QToolButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QLabel)

import frames

class GUI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GUI, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.principalLayout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.controlFrame = QFrame(self) 
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.controlFrame)
        self.principalLayout.addWidget(self.controlFrame)

        self.widgets()

        print (self.bStart)
        print(buttons(self))
    def widgets(self):
        self.bStart = QPushButton('Start')
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.bStart, 0, 0)
        self.bStart.clicked.connect(lambda: self.hide_layout(self.bStart, self.bStop))

        self.bStop = QPushButton('Stop')
        self.bStop.clicked.connect(lambda: self.hide_layout(buttons(self)))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.bStop, 0, 2)

    def hide_layout(self, *args):
        for a in args:
            a.hide()


    def show_layout(self, *args):
        for a in args:
            a.show()

def buttons(self):
    return (self.bStart, self.bStop)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)    
    w = GUI()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

print output bStart button:

```
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QPushButton object at 0x7f089fddac18>
```

print output buttons() function:

```
(<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QPushButton object at 0x7f089fddac18>, <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QPushButton object at 0x7f089fddadc8>)
```

Error bStop button click:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gui.py", line 23, in <lambda>
    self.bStop.clicked.connect(lambda: self.hide_layout(buttons(self)))
  File "gui.py", line 28, in hide_layout
    a.hide()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'hide'
```

Comment: Because a tuple doesn't have that method. Why not focus on why `a` is bound to a tuple instead of the object you thought it would reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to unpack the `tuple`:

```
self.bStop.clicked.connect(lambda: self.hide_layout(*buttons(self)))
```

Answer (score 1):

`buttons` returns tuple, which you then pass as *one argument* to the `self.hide_layout()` method. That method treats each argument as an object to hide:

```
for a in args:
    a.hide()
```

Here `args` is a sequence of all arguments, and `a` one of those arguments. Since you passed in the tuple directly, that's the one argument.

If you wanted to hide the objects *contained in* the tuple, apply the tuple contents as separate arguments:

```
lambda: self.hide_layout(*buttons(self))
```

or change the signature of `hide_layout()` to only accept one argument, which you then treat as a sequence:

```
def hide_layout(self, args):   # note, no *
```

The same would apply to the `show_layout()` method.